# PDO insert not working without error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert data using PDO, but its not working and also its not showing errors in error log and catch block. The select works, the delete works, but the insert doesn't. What's wrong? What can I do to fix it?. Please help me guys.

```
public function storeCoAuthorAffiliations($affiliationData) {
    try {
        unset($affiliationData['affiliationId']);
        //unset($affiliationData['coAuthorId']);
        print_r($affiliationData);
        $this->core->dbh->beginTransaction();
        // insert query
        $stmt = $this->core->dbh->prepare("
                INSERT INTO co_author_profile_affiliations
                       (user_id,co_author_id,department,university,
                        city,country,pincode,website,
                        mobile_personal,phone_office,
                        email_personal,email_office,
                        fax,funding_agency_id)
                 values(:userId,:coAuthorId,:department,:university,
                        :city,:country,:pincode,:website,
                        :mobilePersonal,:phoneOffice,
                        :emailPersonal,:emailOffice,
                        :fax,:fundingAgencyId)");

        $result = $stmt->execute($affiliationData);
        if ($result) {
            $affiliationId = $this->core->dbh->lastInsertId();
            $this->core->dbh->commit();
            return $affiliationId;
        } else {

            // Failed to create user
            $this->core->dbh->rollBack();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //$this->core->dbh->rollBack();
        echo $e->getMessage();   
        return false;
    }
}
```

and $affiliationData array is,

```
Array
(
[:userId] => 35
[:coAuthorId] => 15
[:department] => cse
[:university] => xxx university
[:city] => xxxx
[:country] => xxxx
[:pincode] => xxxx
[:website] => xxxx.com
[:mobilePersonal] => xxxxx
[:phoneOffice] => xxxxxx
[:emailPersonal] => xxxxx@xxx.com
[:emailOffice] => xxxx@xxx.com
[:fax] => 222222222
[:fundingAgencyId] => 5556
)
```

Comment: its a $affiliationData array

Comment: `coAuthorId` is missing in `$affiliationData`??

Comment: `coAuthorId` is not there in array

Comment: so why the array keys doesn't start with `:`?

Comment: is there but still now not working

Comment: Also you are using Exceptions and also testing return statuses. The rollback should be in the `catch` as if you actually get an exception in the `->execute()` **you will be sent directly into the `catch` block** and not run the `if ($result)` test at all.

Comment: @AlonEitan The array id's do not actually have to start with a `:` colon

Comment: Did you actually set Exception Processing in the database connection?

Comment: @RiggsFolly They don't?? Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: `:` Now its there, but its still now not working

Comment: @MansoorH - Yes, I thought it were mandatory, turns out I was wrong

Comment: try setting  before prepare `$this->core->dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );` and then use `print_r($stmt->errorInfo());` in else part

Comment: Yes now its working. issue is duplicate entry. thanks guys. @Undefined_variable

Comment: You dont seem to have a particularly good grip on the Exception error processing or transactions. What is the use in starting a transaction to do one insert that you commit as soon as it has run